# Electrum Wallet, Coinsquare source

Tags: transactions

I am new to this bitcoin wallet use. I have funds allocated to Coinsquare but have yet to buy a single bitcoin or fraction of one. My question is,....... do I need a certain wallet for use in conjunction with a certain funding source? Will my Electrum wallet receive crypto currency from my Coinsquare account?

Answer (score 1):

Its late answer but anyhow.

Definitely you don't need to have wallet linked to and funding source.
Actually opposite : your wallet must be independent from any financial entities and trusting only blockchain.

Yes your Electrum wallet will receive crypto currency. But why ask? Just send small amount for test!

My favorite wallet for bitcoin is Eclair Mobile just in case u need one.